# ANALYZE or EXPLAIN for previous query

Tags: mysql, query-performance, mariadb, execution-plan, explain

`EXPLAIN SELECT ...` shows the EXPLAIN for a query (without actually running it).

`SHOW EXPLAIN FOR conn_id` shows the EXPLAIN for a query that is currently running.

Is it possible to get the EXPLAIN for the last query that ran on a connection?

For example, if my application detected that a specific query took over 2 seconds to run for a user, I'd like to log the `EXPLAIN` or `ANALYZE` with the query plan of that query.

I'm not sure that re-running the query with `EXPLAIN` or `ANALYZE` will give me the exact query plan that was used on its previous run, as MySQL/MariaDB could potentially use another query plan on the re-run.

(I am aware of `log_slow_verbosity=query_plan,explain`, but I don't want to log this for every query that takes over 1 second - only this specific query)

Comment: "never runs" -- perhaps you mean "never finishes" or "has not yet finished after hours"?

Comment: "potentially use another query plan" -- I have always believed that, but I have not found proof of such, even after thousands of Explains.

Comment: "never runs" just means that MySQL/MariaDB don't actually run the query when you do `EXPLAIN SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

"potentially use another query plan" -- I have always believed that, but I have not found proof of such, even after thousands of Explains.

I have seen as many as 6 different `EXPLAINs` for a given 'digest' -- The variation came from different constants in the queries.  I used to capture the slowlogs from a hundred servers and would probe them to get the Explains (before the existence of `log_slow_verbosity`).

You seem to have found all the ways there are to see an Explain.

One caution -- when there is a subquery, `EXPLAIN` *may* evaluate that subquery as part of its work.  This *could* lead to the Explain taking much more than the milliseconds it normally take.

I have no qualms about leaving the slowlog on, even on busy production machines.  (But with `long_quer_time` of at least 1.)

What version are you running?  Note that newer versions have a way to limit statement execution time.

If you would like to discuss an particularly naughty query, start a new Question with the query, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  Explain tells you what is is doing, but not what to change (eg indexing) to make it faster.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I use `SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=10` for this query, but 99.99% takes less than 0.5 seconds to run. Just when it takes over 1 second, the system logs that it took over 1 second, but I'd like more information than that. I guess the closest I have is to re-run the query with `EXPLAIN`, when that happens. I have MariaDB 10.8. I also raised MDEV-29944 in their JIRA.

Comment: @Nuno - Is it `ENGINE=InnoDB`?  (MyISAM is more prone to having mysteriously long executions times.)  Turn on the slowlog with `log_slow_verbosity` and `long_query_time=1` until it happens again.

Comment: I use InnoDB, and I have a `long_query_time`, but I don't want it to be 1, as that would cause too much noise. Like I said, this specific query is 99.99% running in less than 0.5 seconds. I just want a query plan logged in the very rare cases where this takes longer than 1 second. But not for ALL other queries. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Nuno - If you have lots of queries taking more than 1 second, set a higher limit; fix the worst; then lower it.  I'm suspicious of any query taking more than 1 second.

Comment: I understand, but it really depends on the type/nature of the application, what's it used for, what data it queries and processes, the users that run queries, etc. And some queries are much more crucial than others. Anyway - thanks for your help!